# How to create a function that stacks arches side by side (forming a circle)?

Tags: javascript, math

I want to create a function that stacks arches in the following fashion:

[image]

(This is a simplified version. In the real app, there could be more arches.)
Each arch has a `length` of `42`. The `rotation` that places the arch in the upper center is `158`.

I'm very bad at math, so this is all I could come up with:

```
positionArches () {
  const archWidth = 42
  const arches = [
    { name: 'arch1', rotation: 0 }, // must change the rotation
    { name: 'arch2', rotation: 0 },
    { name: 'arch3', rotation: 0 }
  ]
  if (this.isOdd) {
    // 1 arch: [158]
    // 3 arches: [158 - archLength, 158, 158 + archLength] // smaller to larger
  } else {
    // 2 arches: [158-(archLength/2), 158+(archLength/2)]
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to continue. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need math; use canvas

Comment: @AdamAzad I already have the framework that generates the graphics. I only need the math.

Comment: it should be easy with circle equation. `(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2`

Comment: What if you have more than four of them?

Comment: What do you need maths for? Draw those arcs at the correct location?

Comment: @Rad Lexus I need a function because the number of `arches` could vary.

Comment: @trincot Guess I'll create a `next batch` arrow in the last arch or something like that. I want to start simple for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that the `arches` array contains as many arches as you need to position, you can do this:

```
arches.forEach(function (arch, i) {
    arch.rotation = 180 - arches.length * 21 + i * 42;
});
```

Note that if you have more than 4 arches, they will start to overlap.

Also note that if your arches have a size of 42 degrees, then 158 is one degree off from the ideal position: it should be 159.

Comment: Thanks! One question: why 180? And where is 158 being used?

Comment: 158 is not used. 180 is what I assume you consider the angle point at the top of the circle. It was not clear in your question although it seemed that you increase angles in clockwise direction. With 158 and 42 given, the middle of a single arch would arrive at 179, which seemed very close to the 180 degree point (half of a circle), so I think you really have a circle where 180 would be the top point. In that case the single arch should start at 159 (the formula results in that), not 158.